Error message when uploading a file from an LWC and associating it with a contact
Currently, I'm uploading a file in the attached lwc from experience cloud. Here is my js, html, and controller to take a file and associate it with a contact:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Upload" icon-name="utility:upload">
        <lightning-file-upload
            label="Upload Files"
            name="fileUploader"
            record-id={contactId}
            multiple
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
        </lightning-file-upload>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContactIdFromLoggedInUser from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploadController.getContactIdFromLoggedInUser';
import saveFileAndAssociateWithContact from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploadController.saveFileAndAssociateWithContact';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    
export default class FileUploadExpCloud extends LightningElement {
    contactId;

    @wire(getContactIdFromLoggedInUser)
    wiredContactId({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data ----- ', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.contactId = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error fetching contact',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                })
            );
        }
    }

    async handleUploadFinished(event) {

        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        console.log('uploadedFiles ----- ', uploadedFiles);
        try {
            console.log('this.contactId --- ', this.contactId);

            const fileIds = uploadedFiles.map(file => file.documentId);
            console.log('fileIds --- ', JSON.stringify(fileIds[0]));

            await saveFileAndAssociateWithContact({ contactId: this.contactId, fileIds });

            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: `${uploadedFiles.length} file(s) uploaded and associated with the contact successfully.`,
                    variant: 'success',
                })
            );
        } catch (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                })
            );
        }
    }
}


public with sharing class FileUploadController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Id getContactIdFromLoggedInUser() {
        System.debug('getContactIdFromLoggedInUser --- ');
        System.debug('UserId --- '+ UserInfo.getUserId());
        User currentUser = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        if (currentUser.ContactId == null) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('No associated contact found for the logged-in user.');
        }
        return currentUser.ContactId;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveFileAndAssociateWithContact(Id contactId, List<Id> fileIds) {
        System.debug('saveFileAndAssociateWithContact --- ');
        if (contactId == null || fileIds == null || fileIds.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid parameters: contactId and fileIds are required.');
        }

        List<ContentDocumentLink> links = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        for (Id fileId : fileIds) {
            links.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = fileId,
                LinkedEntityId = contactId,
                ShareType = 'I',
                Visibility = 'AllUsers'
            ));
        }
        insert links;
    }
}

It works, but I get an error in dev console:

14:19:10:099 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Document with ID: 069SL000001Ur38 is already linked with the entity with ID: 001SL000004xWw2: [LinkedEntityId]

how can I fix the code or change the configuration in salesforce to keep this error condition from happening?

Documentation about record-id attribute of lightning-file-upload states:

The record Id of the record that the uploaded file is associated to

Indeed since you set it, once the user upload a file, it will be linked to that record (the contact), that's why when you try to link it again in your apex method, you got an error stating "Document with ID: XXX is already linked with the entity".
So in handleUploadFinished method you only need to show the success toast.

That solved the issue - thanks @RubenDG
